# How to determine if a set is a power set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is a given set a power set?

For example:

Is the following set `x` a power set? `{{1, 2}, {1}, {2}, {}}`.

Comment: Why would you ask this question here if you answered it yourself in a matter of seconds?

Comment: "Answer your own question" is available as an option on the page where you write the question, a valid use of SE. I thought of this question because somone was asking about it in the chat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Find the member of `x` that itself contains the most elements, in this case `{1, 2}`. If there is more than one possibility, then `x` is not a power set.

Step 2: The power set of `{1, 2}` is `{{1, 2}, {1}, {2}, {}}`, call this 'y'.

Step 3: `x` is a power set only if `x` = `y`.